# gradle junit test report is not in xml format

Tags: android, xml, junit, android-gradle-plugin

I'm setting up CI for an Android gradle project.  To report back into CI I need the standard junit xml formatted report file.

On test failure this is the output I get

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Mobile Application:testDevelopmentDebugUnitTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at:         file://path/build/reports/tests/developmentDebug/index.html
```

When I search under the build path for any xml files none exist.

I'm using 3.3. version of gradle
and here are some of the pertinent build.gradle details

```
android {
    dependencies {

        //test project dependencies
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'

        // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
        // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing in order to get a junit formatted xml report.

Comment: Are you trying run unit tests or espressotests? 'Application:testDevelopmentDebugUnitTest' is for unit tests. For espresso tests it would something like :connectedDevelopmentDebugAndroidTest (depending on your build variants)

Comment: @ksondore, please mark the answer as solution, if feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for "How to get JUnit XML from Gradle"

Looks like (in Gradle 5.0) it works with;

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

test {
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' // didn't work with jupiter/version5
}
```

... but your results may vary.

Comment: This is not working for me. No folder is created after adding the test {} code when using ```grade test```. Using latest gradle version coming bundled with latest stable Android Studio on Win10.

Comment: This solution is not working for Android Gradle projects. It works fine with jUnit 5 in pure Kotlin modules.